# QCompleter in QTreeView not completing expected column

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview, qcompleter

I am installing a QCompleter on a QTreeView via a QStyledItemDelegate. My QStandardItemModel looks something like the following:

```
Item 1
  \_ Item A, Item B, Item C
  \_ Item D, Item E, Item F
Item 2
  \_ Item G, Item H, Item I
```

In the subclassed delegate I have the following code:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    completer = QtGui.QCompleter(index.model(), parent)
    completer.setCompletionRole(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
    completer.setCompleterColumn(0) # here's where it gets weird
    edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
    edit.setCompleter(completer)
    return edit
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to get my completer to search child items in my hierarchical tree. For example it will only return "Item 1, Item 2" but not "Item A, Item D". It seems like I'm missing a "setParentItem()" function or something...

Here's some "working" code which manually does what I want, however I would like to know how to do this on the model directly:

```
string_list = []
for row in range(index.model().itemFromIndex(index.parent()).rowCount):
    string_list.append(index.model().sibling(row, index.column(), index).data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))

completer = QtGui.QCompleter(string_list, parent)
edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
edit.setCompleter(competer)
```

Comment: Do you want the completer to return the children of the item where the editor is? Or do you want all the items in the model to be shown?

Comment: Yes, all siblings of this column. So for example if the editor index is `Item A` I would want `Item A` and `Item D`

Comment: okay, and if it's in `Item 1`, it should show the options `Item 1` and `Item 2`, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc That is correct. I updated my Q to have an example which should demonstrate the behavior I'm looking for.